What is a suitable measure to determine whether a superimposed line is on a grid line?
I have an image  of a rotated grid. This grid has slightly darker pixels which I'm trying to detect. Due to the nature of the problem, my solution is to superimpose a grid onto the image which I can control - then just measure the validity of that grid.
Herein lies my problem. The method I'm using to detect the validity of a line is to determine how many pixels of the line are smaller than the mean of the line (on the basis that the mean of the line should be low, so the ones that are smaller are aligned properly), however this is very ineffective.
Here's an example grid: 
The blue grid is the manufactured grid that I have control over, and there is low accuracy (~40%, under the heading 'validity') for this grid as it is not aligned.
But when I do a sweep of the parameter space, my best grid turns out like this:  As we can see, there's a 50% accuracy measure on a grid that is nowhere aligned!
So what would be the best measure for this line to decide whether it's actually aligned to the grid?
